# Reporting score to gamecenter for ios7

Tags: ios7, game-center

According to https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/LeaderBoards/LeaderBoards.html

Reporting score to gamecenter in ios7 should be done using

```
[GKLeaderboard reportScores:scores withCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
//Do something interesting here.
}];
```

However, I could not find any reference to this method in GKLeaderboard.

The method does not exist here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKLeaderboard_Ref/Reference/Reference.html

GKLeaderboard.h does not contain a reportScores method also.

The former way of reporting score using GKScore's reportScoreWithCompletionHandler method had been deprecated so I am reluctant to use that.

Does anyone know whats the correct way to report score to gamecenter in ios7?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I can confirm that the reportScores:withCompletionHandler: method does work; I'm using it in one of my apps. It's located in the header file GKScore.h. This is how I'm using it:

```
- (void) reportHighScore:(NSInteger) highScore {
    if ([GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].isAuthenticated) {
        GKScore* score = [[GKScore alloc] initWithLeaderboardIdentifier:MY_LEADERBOARD_ID];
        score.value = highScore;
        [GKScore reportScores:@[score] withCompletionHandler:^(NSError *error) {
            if (error) {
                // handle error
            }
        }];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, apparently the instance method had been deprecated but the class method had not. I will use this method for now. In apple's dev reference they split the example between iOS 6 & 7 so I am sure they intend it to be done in a different way. Its just strange that the intended way for iOS7 is not documented properly.

Comment: Sometimes Apple's documentation is just wrong. I tend to trust what's in the class documentation more than what's in the overview. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKScore_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/GKScore/reportScores:withCompletionHandler:

Comment: I was faced with this problem also. It looks like Apple needs to review their documentation more carefully before publishing them as it creates a lot of confusion and waste of time...

Comment: I tried this solution and it works great in sandbox. Unfortunately now my game has gone live, but the scores are not being reported.

Comment: How do I reference this method? I tried [self ..] but reportHighScore does not show up? Can anyone help me out??

Comment: Just a question, but did you send that feedback to Apple?  This is a year later and the docs still are out of date.  I'd expect Apple to be on top of that.